# Delete record in Core Data with CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

I would like delete a record in the Core Data when you tap on a close button in your CollectionView Cell. I made a UIButton in the Collection View Cell controller with an extension in the CollectionView Controller file.

The indexPath give a number and I made the let deleteCellNumber, but I received the error:

> 'Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath.Element (aka 'Int') to expected argument type 'NSManagementObject'

```
extension soundboardVC: SoundboardCellDelegate {
    func delete(cell: soundboardCellVC) {

        if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {

            let soundRequest:NSFetchRequest<Soundboard> = Soundboard.fetchRequest()
            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            let deleteCellNumber = indexPath[1]

            context.delete(deleteCellNumber)

            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                soundBoardData = try managedObjectContext.fetch(soundRequest)
            } catch {
                print("Fetching Failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the error, but use `indexPath.item` rather than `indexPath[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very clear:

`context.delete(...` expects an `NSManagedObject` instance but you pass an integer (by the way `indexPath[1]` is a pretty spooky but valid way to get the `item` / `row` value).

Assuming you have a data source array `soundBoardData` the usual way to delete Core Data objects in a collection or table view is

```
extension soundboardVC: SoundboardCellDelegate {
    func delete(cell: soundboardCellVC) {

        if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) {

            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let itemToDelete = soundBoardData[indexPath.item]
            soundBoardData.remove(at: indexPath.item)
            context.delete(itemToDelete)
            collectionView!.deleteItems(at: indexPath)
            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
    }
}
```

Don't refetch the data, delete in the item in the data source array, then delete the item in the managed object context, remove the row from the collection view (with animation) and save the context.